# Adding an event listener on load for floating label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On page reloads I have floating labels overlapping the input text if the form has been filled out before. To avoid this problem I want to alter the input text's style if there is data in the form.

Here is my code:

https://codepen.io/holly-williford/pen/pONYYM

```
document.getElementsByClassName("floating").addEventListener("load", hideLabel);

function hideLabel() {
    if(!$('input').val() ) {
        $('floating').addClass('warning');
    } else {

    }
}


<label class="floating">Test</label>
<input></input> 

warning {
    color: red; 
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do querySelectorAll, getElementsByClassName and other getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method)

Comment: I don't understand the problem.

Comment: Why are you using `.getElementsByTagName()` and `.addEventListener()` when you have jQuery?

Comment: A `<label>` doesn’t trigger a `load` event. An `<input>` doesn’t have a closing tag `</input>`. `$("floating")` implies `<floating>` elements. You want `$(".floating")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many things from the codepen example that need changes.

1. HTML

```html
<label class="floating">Test</label>
    <input> <!-- You should have a proper html tag -->
```

2. CSS

```css
 .warning { //Notice the '.'
    color: red; 
  }
```

3. JS

```js
    window.onload = hideLabel;
    function hideLabel() {
        if(!$('input').val() ) {
              $('.floating').addClass('warning'); // Notice the '.'
        } else {
         
        }
    }
```

These modifications should help you get started.

But, you have mentioned jQuery and you don't seem to make the most of it.